# Extension field notation

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

Let $F_p[x]$ be a ring of polynomials with coefficients in the field $F_p$. Let $q(x)$ be some irreducible polinomial in the base field $F_p$ with degree $n$. To construct the field extension $F_p^n$, I've seen in literature two different notations/constructions:

1) $F_p^n = F_p[x]/\langle q(x) \rangle$ : quotient ring by the *ideal* generated by $q(x)$

and

2) $F_p^n = F_p[x]/( q(x) )$ : the residue class by $q(x)$, when operations are done $\mod q(x)$.

Now I ask: These different notations means the same? Why one might be preferable instead the other?

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/16157/242) for the general relationship between congruences, quotient rings and subalgebras of the square.

Comment: They are exactly the same.

Comment: quotienting out an ideal $I$ and doing arithmetic with the cosets is exactly what you get when you quotient out by the equivalence relation $a ~ b$ iff $a-b \in I$ and define addition and multiplication on the equivalence classes in the natural way.

Comment: @M.Van They are certainly not "exactly the same", but there is a general correspondence. See the link in my prior comment.

Comment: @BillDubuque How are they not the same sets with the same ring structure on them (not only isomorphic, but the isomorphism is given by the identity -.-)?

Comment: @M.Van This is explained in the link I provided (and its links).

Comment: @Bill Dubuque, is it not true that by definition $R/I = R/\!\equiv$ as sets, where $I$ is ideal in $R$ and $\equiv$ is congruence generated by $I$?

Comment: @Ennar It depends on how one presents the constructions. I suspect that those who think that they are "exactly the same" have not given enough thought to the general case (e.g. [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/894257/242) for the ideal analog for general algebras - so-called *ideal-determined* algebras). But it is pointless to argue the matter without a precise definition of "exactly the same". In any case readers may find it insighful to examine these  matters from the more general perspective in the links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are exactly the same (note though that this field is written $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$, not $\mathbb{F}_p^n$).  "Residue classes mod $q(x)$" and "elements of the quotient by the ideal generated by $q(x)$" are two different terms for the same thing: namely, equivalence classes of elements of $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ under the equivalence relation $f(x)\sim g(x)$ iff $f(x)-g(x)$ is a multiple of $q(x)$.  The difference in notation between $(q(x))$ and $\langle q(x)\rangle$ is meaningless--some people use parentheses to denote ideals generated by a list of elements, and other people use angle brackets.  You should feel free to use either one, as long as you are consistent.