# Fractions: cross-multiply equivalence is least with $\frac{a}b\approx \frac{ac}{bc}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation, fractions, equivalence-relations

### Background

The following is a paraphrasing of E. B. Vinberg's *A Course of Algebra*, page 129, discussing the construction of quotient fields.

> Let $A$ be an integral domain. Consider the set of pairs $(a,b)$ where $a,b \in A, b\neq0$. Define an equivalence relation [on this set of pairs] by the following rule: $$(a_1,b_1) \sim (a_2,b_2) \overset{\text{def}}{\Longleftrightarrow} a_1b_2=a_2b_1.$$

The above definition is reasonable. I also understand this statement, $(3.34)$,

> The above definition implies that $$(a,b) \sim (ac,bc) \tag{3.34}$$ for any $c\neq0$.

Now next comes the part that is unclear to me. Especially the equality marked by $(*)$; the asterisk is not present in the book.

> On the other hand, any equivalence $(a_1,b_1) \sim (a_2,b_2)$ is a **corollary** of equivalences of the form $(3.34)$, as the following chain of equivalences demostrates: $$(a_1,b_1) \sim (a_1b_2,b_1b_2) \overset{(*)}{=} (a_2b_1,b_1b_2) \sim (a_2,b_2).$$ (We first multiplied both entries in $(a_1,b_1)$ by $b_2$ and then cancelled $b_1$ in both entries of the resulting pair.)

The emphasis is also added by me.

### Question

As I understand the passage, we are trying to show that we can prove any equivalence $(a_1,b_1) \sim (a_2,b_2)$ by using some other equivalence of the type $(3.34)$. It is clear to me why $(a_1,b_1) \sim (a_1b_2,b_1b_2)$ and $(a_2b_1,b_1b_2) \sim (a_2,b_2)$ hold, as they directly use relationship $(3.34)$ and multiplication commutativity in $A$.

However, I fail to understand the equality denoted by $(*)$: $(a_1b_2,b_1b_2) \overset{(*)}{=} (a_2b_1,b_1b_2)$. It is supposed to be an equality of ordered pairs. That is, $(*)$ is true by definition iff $a_1b_2 = a_2b_1 \land b_1b_2 = b_1b_2$. The latter part of the conjunction is clear but the first half $a_1b_2 = a_2b_1$ is equivalent to our definition of $(a_1,b_1) \sim (a_2,b_2)$. Yet this is what we wish to show (cf. ***corollary***), and hence one cannot assume $(a_1,b_1) \sim (a_2,b_2)$ is true when it is exactly what we are trying to demonstrate.

***Q:*** How does $(a_1b_2,b_1b_2) \overset{(*)}{=} (a_2b_1,b_1b_2)$ when $(a_1,b_1) \sim (a_2,b_2)$ is not yet known? Wherein does my misunderstanding lie?

Comment: I added a complete argument to my answer. This elementary approach is almost surely what Vinberg intended since the book includes no prior discussion of general properties of equivalence relations. Vinberg's argument is far from clear so it is not surprising that it might prove perplexing to one first encountering these ideas. If anything remains unclear then let me know and I will be happy to elaborate.

Comment: **Note to future readers.** The title of the question was edited (I assume) to make this question more easily found in the future. Do not get the impression that I knew the answer before asking. Because once it is clear *what* is being proven, the proof itself becomes much simpler. :)

Comment: Yes, that's why I edited the title. Unfortunately this key conceptual idea is rarely mentioned in algebra textbooks (and when it is often the essence of the matter is obfuscated as here). So anything we can do here to remedy this it time well spent.

Comment: It is even [more obscure](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2446191/242) in the case of general rings of fractions (localizations) where the cross multiply rule becomes $\, s ad = scb\,$ for some denominator $\,s,\,$ but a similar argument works as in my answer (here it is convenient to also use $\ (a,b) \simeq (c,d)\!\! \!\overset{\rm def}\iff  (as,bs) = (ct,dt) \,$ for some $\,s,t\in S = $ denominator set. $\ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intuitively, the point is to show that  the cross-multiplication rule for fraction equivalence $(\sim)$  is  the smallest equivalence relation $(\approx)$ equating $\,a/b\,$ and $\,ad/(bd)\,$ for all $\,d\neq 0$, i.e. satisfying $(3.34)$.

The unclear part  shows $(a,b)\sim (c,d) \Rightarrow \, (a,b)\approx (c,d),\,$ i.e. any $\rm\color{#c00}{equiv}$. relation $\approx$ satisfying $(3.34)$ includes all  relations in $\,\sim.\,$ So, being an equiv. relation satisfying $(3.34),\,$ $\sim\,$ is  the smallest such.

Below we give a very  detailed presentation of the argument. Recall that the relation $(3.34)$ is
 $$(a,b)\, \approx\, (ad,bd)\ \ \ {\rm  for\ any}\,\ d\neq 0\qquad\qquad \tag{3.34}$$

To show that $\,\sim\,$ is the *smallest* $\rm\color{#c00}{equivalence}$ relation satisfying $(3.34)$ it suffices to show that any such equivalence relation $\,\approx\,$ includes all elements of $\,\sim,\,$ i.e. if $\,(f,g)\,$ is in $\,\sim\,$ then $\,(f,g)\,$ is in $\,\approx,\,$ i.e. $\,f\sim g\,\Rightarrow\, f\approx g.\ $ The Lemma below proves this. The proof outline, in common notation, is

$$\dfrac{a}b\sim \dfrac{c}d\,\Rightarrow\,\color{#0a0}{ad = cb}\,\Rightarrow\, \dfrac{a}{b}\,\approx\, \dfrac{\color{#0a0}{a\,d}}{b\,d}\,\approx\,\dfrac{\color{#0a0}{c\,b}}{d\,b}\,\approx\, \dfrac{c}d\qquad\qquad  $$

**Lemma** $\,\ (a,b)\,\sim\, (c,d)\, \Rightarrow \, (a,b)\,\approx\, (c,d)\ $ for any $\rm\color{#c00}{equivalence}$ relation $\,\approx\,$ satisfying $(3.34)$

$\!\begin{align}{\bf Proof}\:\ \ \ \   (a,b)\, &\approx\, (\color{#0a0}{ad},bd)\ \ \ {\rm by}\ \approx\ {\rm satisfies}\ (3.34) \ {\rm and}\ \, d\neq 0 \\[.2em]
&\approx\, (\color{#0a0}{cb},\,db)\ \ \  {\rm by}\ \ \color{#0a0}{ad=cb}\ \ {\rm by\ definition\ of}\,\ (a,b)\sim (c,d)\ \ {\rm and}\ \approx\ \color{#c00}{\rm reflexive}\\[.2em]
&\approx\ (c,d) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ {\rm by}\ \approx\ {\rm satisfies}\ (3.34)\ {\rm and}\  \approx\, {\rm\color{#c00}{symmetric}\ and}\,\ b\neq 0\\[.2em]
\Rightarrow\ \ (a,b)\, &\approx\, (c,d)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \, {\rm by}\ \approx\  \rm \color{#c00}{transitive}
\end{align}$

Note that above we (implicitly) used commutativity of multiplication: $\, bd = db$.

Comment: Reply to your comment under the question as well as answer: Yes, I suppose this is what Vinberg had in mind. The word *corollary* threw me off entirely, and indeed, Vinberg does not exactly say that this smallness is what is being proven. Would you also agree that in the quote "*On the other hand, any equivalence $(a_1,b_1) \sim (a_2,b_2)$ is a corollary of...*" the symbol $\sim$ aqcuires a new meaning. That is, in that chain $\sim$ no longer designates the relation $a_1b_2 = a_2b_1$ but rather any equivalence relation satisfying $(3.34)$?

Comment: @Linear Yes, that's why I chose different symbols. Certainly the exposition there could be much better so it is not your fault that it was not immediately clear. This is one of the reasons that teaching is so difficult. To excel at teaching requires the capability to easily *forget* key ideas in order to revert to a prior (lower) knowledge level of the average reader in order to make the exposition accessible at that level. Alas, Vinberg didn't forget enough here.

Comment: Agreed. Just to be sure not to be too rough on Vinberg: most of the time Vinberg isn't too chatty but the proofs are sometimes excellent. Also, I have been having some answer-accepting anxiety since there are two great and mostly equivalent answers to my question. I decided to use a random number generator (0 to 50 being Lee, and 51 to 100 being you). Congratulations are in order, as '68' popped out.

Comment: @Linear Pretty random!  Usually I recommend that one accepts the answer that one thinks will be most helpful to others at your level. What Lee wrote is correct, but I doubt that's what Vinberg had in mind. In fact it is rare that any mention of generation of equivalence relations is explicitly mentioned in a first course in Abstract Algebra since it is not needed for the most common topics. It sometimes occurs in second courses, and almost always in courses on Universal Algebra (where congruences vs. ideals [become more central](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/894257/242)).

Comment: If you're willing, you may join me at a chatroom I created: [Brief discussion: Quotient Fields (cont.)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95631/brief-discussion-quotient-fields-cont). It should take about 15 minutes of your time, hopefully. If you don't have time, this is perfectly OK.

Comment: @Linear Post any further questions on this main site, and link to this question. (chatrooms are essentially trash bins, e.g. content is not searched, links aren't handled properly,  answers can't be up/donwvoted, etc).

Comment: I understand the motivation in asking a new question instead of chatting, of course, but I think in this case the question would *not* be well received, and probably with just cause. It would either be a longish and quote-ish wall of text, or presuppose an answerer having read some other question which is not a good idea, AFAIK. Maybe, if our chat is successful and the outcome turns out to be useful to others, we could afterwards decide to post the Q/A?

Comment: @Linear The question will be well received - don't worry about that. You can post a draft in the meta sandbox and run it by me if you are really worried about that. Trust me, this is the best way for all (not only you and I).  On a personal note, I highly loathe the poorly designed chat platform, so I avoid it as much as possible (but that's far from the major reason for said recommendation).

Comment: I will think about your suggestion. By the way (if you are not aware), I already posted the "full" question (w Mathjax) into the chat room before I pinged you here. Otherwise, a long time would have passed before we could start proper discussion. Of course, were I to decide to post it as a question, it would require a different introduction as the current version was intended specifically with you in mind.

Comment: @Linear That's a fine question for the main site. If you post it on main *everyone* benefits from the answers (and you'll likely get multiple viewpoints). Win-win for all. Chat is lose-lose for almost all.

Comment: Okay, you've won me over. I've posted the question, here it is: [How to flesh out Vinberg's argument: Quotient field operations are well-defined](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3281092/how-to-flesh-out-vinbergs-argument-quotient-field-operations-are-well-defined) if you wish to chime in.

Answer (score 3):

The full statement of what is being proved here is that the equivalence relation [on this set of pairs] that is described in your first box is "generated by" the relation in your second box (3.34), or to say this more formally, the first is the reflexive-symmetric-transitive closure of the second.

The logic of the argument goes like this:

- Given $a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2 \in A$, if $b_1 \ne 0$, if $b_2 \ne 0$, and if $a_1 b_2 = b_1 a_2$, then the ordered pair $\bigl((a_1,b_1),(a_2,b_2)\bigr)$ is an element of the reflexive-symmetric-transitive closure of the relation (3.34). Or to put this more informally, the relation $(a_1,b_1) \sim (a_2,b_2)$ may be deduced by a finite chain of relations in the reflexive-symmetric-transitive closure of the relation (3.34).

Notice: We are not trying to *show* that $a_1 b_2 = b_1 a_2$. Instead we are *assuming* that equation to be true in the integral domain $A$, and you may use this equation in your calculations. Equation (*) is exactly where this equation is being used.

Comment: Note that we don't need to invoke any knowledge of the structure of generated equivalence relations in order to prove (or comprehend) the claim - see my answer.

Comment: This is just a point of language. One can decide to take for granted the existence of the "smallest" equivalence relation, if one so desires. But then that raises a mathematical question about why the "smallest" exists, and I chose language which suggests why that is so without committing to that decision. The "smallest" equivalence relation containing a given relation is simply the reflexive-symmetric-transitive closure of the given relation.

Comment: And, of course, instead of saying "the smallest equivalence relation..." one can use the alternate language of "the equivalence relation generated by...", which is what I chose.

Comment: In general yes, but the point is that we don't need such generality *here* since the argument in my answer *proves* that $\sim$ is smallest.

Comment: @LeeMosher On its own, how do you define the relation $(3.34)$? Simply as $(a,b) \sim' (d, e) \overset{\text{def}}{\Longleftrightarrow} \exists c\in A\ (c\neq 0 \land d = ac \land e = bc)$, that is simply as the set $\left\{((a,b),(ca,cb))\mid(a,b)\in A^2, b\neq0, c\in A\setminus\{0\}\right\}$, I assume?

Comment: That's exactly correct.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Lee! Due to answer-accepting anxiety, I obted to use a random number generator. Commiserations, and my thanks once again!